# Does Paint.breakText include the character at the maxWidth?

Tags: android, paint

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#breakText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20float,%20float[])) for `Paint.breakText` says

> **breakText**
>
> ```
> int breakText (CharSequence text,  
>                int start,  
>                int end,  
>                boolean measureForwards,  
>                float maxWidth,  
>                float[] measuredWidth)
> ```
>
> Measure the text, stopping early if the measured width exceeds
>   maxWidth. Return the number of chars that were measured, and if
>   measuredWidth is not null, return in it the actual width measured.
>
> Returns
>   `int`     The number of chars that were measured. Will always be <= abs(end
>   - start).

It is unclear whether or not the number of characters returned includes the one that made it exceed `maxWidth` since that character was presumably measured before determining that the total measured width exceeded the `maxWidth`.

That is, if my red line represents the `maxWidth`, would it include the `o` of `World` in the image below?

[image]

*I am answering my question below as a self-answer.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, `breakText` does not include the character that makes it exceed `maxWidth`.**

We can see this with the following code.

```
String text = "Hello World";
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(100);

// Measure the substrings individually
int length = text.length();
for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    float totalWidth = paint.measureText(text, 0, i);
    Log.i("TAG", i + ", totalWidth of " + text.substring(0, i) + ": " + totalWidth);
}

// compare these to breakText
float[] measuredWidth = new float[1];
float maxWidth = 360; // halfway through the "o" of "World"
int countedChars = paint.breakText(text, 0, length, true, maxWidth, measuredWidth);
Log.i("TAG", "countedChars: " + countedChars + " (\"" + text.substring(0, countedChars) + "\")");
Log.i("TAG", "measuredWidth: " + measuredWidth[0]);

// 1, totalWidth of H: 70.0
// 2, totalWidth of He: 123.0
// 3, totalWidth of Hel: 148.0
// 4, totalWidth of Hell: 173.0
// 5, totalWidth of Hello: 230.0
// 6, totalWidth of Hello : 255.0
// 7, totalWidth of Hello W: 344.0
// 8, totalWidth of Hello Wo: 399.0
// 9, totalWidth of Hello Wor: 433.0
//10, totalWidth of Hello Worl: 458.0
//11, totalWidth of Hello World: 515.0

// countedChars: 7 ("Hello W")
// measuredWidth: 342.0
```

[image]

Why `measureText` gives a slightly different value (344) than `breakText` (342) does is a different question. My guess is it is probably related to kerning between the `W` and the `o`.